# Integral of the $n$-th root of $\tan(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Recently, I’ve started doing calculus and have ventured my way into the tedious integration of $\tan(x)$ to some specific root.

I’ve started wondering whether there is any generalisation of the integral of the nth root of $\tan(x)$, i.e.

$$\int\sqrt[n]{\tan x}\> dx $$
But I have no idea where to start myself. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you mean integrals of the form $\int \tan^{1 / k} x\,dx$ for positive integers $k$, then a natural substitution transforms the integral to the rational integral $k \int \frac{u^k\, du}{1 + u^{2 k}}$, and so for each $k$ the integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions and real constants. But an expression for the antiderivative for general $k$ won't be particularly enlightening for most purposes.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I apologise, I’m very new to stack exchange. Don’t quite know how to input formulas yet. Basically sqrt(tanx), but for “n” instead of 2.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thanks! You say it won’t be enlightening. Does that mean that there does exist one?

Comment: @KnotTheBest. There is a general formula : it involves a Gaussian hypergeometric function. Do you know this topic ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @KnotTheBest You can typeset the integral in question as `\int \tan^{1 / k} x \,dx` or `\int \sqrt[k]{\tan x} \,dx`.

Comment: And yes, there are a few different expressions for a general formula---one a sum of rational expressions of the form $\frac{A_i}{z - \zeta_i}$, where $\zeta_i$ varies over the roots of $1 + x^{2 k}$ (maybe this can be turned into a real expression with quadratic denominators without excessive trouble), the Gaussian hypergeometric form Claude mentions, and one using the (related) Lerch transcendent function. But I don't think any of them will be particularly helpful to someone self-studying integral calculus.

Comment: If you're still interested in knowing what can be said about a general form, say so here, and I can write a short summary of what can be done, or Claude can, if he likes.

Comment: @TravisWillse A short summary would be amazing, thanks! May not be helpful, but I am curious to see how one would derive such a thing.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No idea what that is(yet). Shall do some googling on that topic, thank you.

Comment: @KnotTheBest Quanto has by now written a good answer given by integrating the real, rational expression with quadratic denominators I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the partial decomposition

\begin{align}
\frac{nt^n}{t^{2n}+1}= \sum_{k=1}^{n}
 \frac{(-1)^{k+1} t\sin \theta_k}{t^2-2t\cos \theta_k +1}, \>\>\>\>\>
 \theta_k=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}
\end{align}
to integrate
\begin{align}
& \int\sqrt[n]{\tan x}\> dx=\int \frac{nt^n}{t^{2n}+1}dx\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{n} {(-1)^{k+1}}\left( \sin \theta_k
\ln\sqrt{t^2 - 2t\cos \theta_k + 1}
+\cos \theta_k
\tan^{-1}\frac{t- \cos \theta_k}{\sin \theta_k}
\right)
\end{align}
where $t= \sqrt[n]{\tan x} $.

Comment: Quite interesting. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the edit aswell.

Comment: Where does the theta sub k come from?

Comment: @KnotTheBest - unit roots of $t^{2n}+1=0$

Comment: Apologies, may be silly, but could you please elaborate some as to how you got the unit roots?

Comment: @KnotTheBest - Note $t=(-1)^{1/2n}=(e^{i(2\pi k-\pi)}) ^{1/2n}=e^{i\theta_k}$